# Append SVG Text at the top of a Bubble Group/Cluster. d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I have these group of bubbles.[image]

And I'm trying to add an svg:text at the top center of each cluster. The problem is I have no way of getting the height of each cluster. I have no problem getting the center.

I tried getting the max height bubble in each cluster after the simulation ends:

```
                .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(0.1).y(heightLevel2)).on('end', () => {
                    var index = 0;
                    clusterHeightList.push(0);
                    d3.selectAll('.chart-bubble circle').each(function () {
                        const el = d3.select(this);
                        
                        if (clusterHeightList[index] < el.attr('cy')) {
                            clusterHeightList[index] = el.attr('cy');
                        }
                        if (data.data.includes(groupBreak)) {
                            clusterHeightList.push(0);
                            index++;
                        }

                        groupBreak++;
                    })
                //More logic where I append SVG text based on the max height of each cluster.
               });
```

The problem is that it is slow, since I have to wait for the simulation to finish. Also it's slightly inaccurate.

I can guesstimate the height but that's never the right way to go about dynamic data.

ideal example of text:
[image]

Any help would be helpful.

side note: I created the data and the grouping off the bubbles. So I know that the distribution of the bubble clusters is correct. I just need to accurately add text near each cluster.

Comment: Does the text *need* to be above the visualization? If the visualizations grow "outward" wouldn't you want the text centralized? Or can you create some sort of normative scale?

Comment: the text needs to be "near" each cluster.  As long as the text isn't overlapping one of the bubbles in the cluster. Side note: each text is describing the total data in the cluster.

Comment: I'm assuming 1) you want a layout like the one above, without knowing exactly why, and 2) that the size of the primary red shape is essentially the important descriptive aspect of the visual.

Comment: The pictures are of bubble groups that I created. The second picture specifically has photoshopped text. The clusters are dispersed in a grid like system on purpose.

Comment: I guessss alternatively I can just get the biggest circle in each cluster on diameter calculation and append text to the biggest bubble. I don't see text overlapping in that case. Or at least often :).

Comment: Use ‘getBBox’ to get the boundaries of the circles and places the text above that.

Comment: wait, @shreshth you're saying I can use getbbox on a only certain collection of elements? All the circles are are wrapped in a g element. In my code I know which circle is part of what group based off an array of indexs denoting the group clusters. That would be great if I could. I'll see how it goes tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I think it'd be easier you put circles in a group in their own `<g>` element. I think you can still run the force simulation with this approach. Or you could do a `d3.min()` on all the x positions for each group. The former approach would be easier IMO.

Comment: This makes total sense. Thank you so much for understanding my question. Great solution.

Comment: eh it works but the positioning is not correct.